# Как получать новый токен для дроп бокса?

Tags: python, dropbox

Залогинился по API в дроп бокс, создал приложение, токен живет сутки. Как получать постоянный токен или как то генерировать может можно их? Чтобы постоянно не заходить и не генерировать из приложения.

Comment: где-то тут читаю, не уверен в надёжности данного источника -> https://www.codemzy.com/blog/dropbox-long-lived-access-refresh-token